# Error while trying create a materialized view in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Getting below error while trying create a materialized view in pyspark sql (HDP 3.1). Is this issue because spark only mange external tables? Do we have alternate solution to create MV thru pyspark.?
error:
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: "\nno viable alternative at input 'CREATE MATERIALIZED'(line 1, pos 7)\n\n== SQL ==\nCREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW